# logstash config file execution error?

Tags: logstash, config

I created a config and saved in bin directory of logstash and wanted to use the config file my giving cmd like this in windows 32

```
C:\Users\5897852\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\bin>logstash -f "C:\Users\5897852\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\bin\logstash.conf"
```

i got an error like this:

> [2016-12-29T17:51:47,591][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No config
>   files found in path 
>   {:path=>"C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/bin/logstash.conf"}
>   [2016-12-29T17:51:47,607][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] failed to
>   fetch pipeline conf iguration {:message=>"No config files found:
>   C:\Users\571952\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\ bin\logstash.conf.

Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"}

Comment: How does your conf look like? And are you sure you've got the exact name of the conf file when you're executing it?

Comment: yeah,i created logstash.config and saved in bin directory of logstash-5.1.1

Comment: actually the code is wrong in logstash.conf file thats why it shown error

Comment: so i changed the code it worked fine..

Comment: Was that the config path you missed out?

Comment: no the code in .config file is not correct ,so thats why it shown the above error

Answer (score 0):

When you're running `logstash` in **Windows**, you need to use the forward slash "/" instead of the normal backslash "\", when you're pointing the path to the `logstash` config file.

Try running it as:

```
logstash -f "C:/Users/5897852/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/bin/logstash.conf"
```

And also make sure that you've given the necessary permissions to the conf file in order to execute.